# Is using a promise inside another promise considered an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a code that looks like this :

```
app.post("/api/exercise/add", function(req, res, next) {
User
 .findById(req.body.userId)
 .exec()
 .then(user => user)
 .then(function(user) {
   let exercise = new Exercise({
     description: req.body.description,
     duration: req.body.duration,
     date: req.body.date, //BUG: must add validations, date accepts 19984-01-01
     user: user
   })
   .save()
   .then(function(exercise) {
     user.exercises.push(exercise)
     user.
      save().
      then(user => res.json({ status: 201, exercises: user.exercises }))
  })
  .catch(err => next(err))
})
.catch(err => next(err));
});
```

Is the fact that I'm using a promise inside another promise, in this case, considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: It's certainly a smell. More of a smell is the fire-and-forget that you're performing when you save.

Comment: You should consider using [async functions](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c)

Comment: @spender, I was hoping that eventual errors would be caught be the next Catch or would they not ?

Comment: If you `return user.save().then(user => res.json({ status: 201, exercises: user.exercises }))` then the value/error will flow through the promise chain. Without returning the promise, you'll fly past the catch while the save is still in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense, it's inelegant - the problem is that it creates unnecessary `.then` nesting. If the `.then` and `.catch` handlers that follow both Promises are the same, you can just `return` the new Promise inside the `.then` to pass it onto the next `.then` or `.catch`, as in the code below.

To pass along multiple variables / Promises to the next `.then` without reassigning an outer variable, use `Promise.all`:

```
app.post("/api/exercise/add", function(req, res, next) {
User
 .findById(req.body.userId)
 .exec()
 .then(function(user) {
   // return the Promise so it can be used by the next then, without nesting
   // because you also need access to `user` in the next then, use Promise.all
   return Promise.all([user, new Exercise({
     description: req.body.description,
     duration: req.body.duration,
     date: req.body.date, //BUG: must add validations, date accepts 19984-01-01
     user: user
   })
   .save()]);
  })
  .then(function([user, exercise]) {
     user.exercises.push(exercise);
     // return the Promise so it can be used by the next then, without nesting:
     return user.save();
   })
   .then(user => res.json({ status: 201, exercises: user.exercises }))
   .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

Note that the

```
.then(user => user)`
```

is completely superfluous - it doesn't do anything, you already have a Promise that resolves to the `user` you want in the next `.then`.

Comment: `.then(function(exercise) { user.exercises.push(exercise) }` raises "user is not defined". The user object doesn't seem to be available in the scope of the exercise promise. I could use some temporary variable to store the user when `findById` is fulfilled, then use it to push to exercise. Is there any way to resolve this heterogenous returns making user available after returning the exercise object ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Promise.all` to pass multiple values along a Promise chain without creating an unnecessary outside variable, see edit

Answer (score 1):

We can have something like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  let x = 25; 
  if (x%2 === 0) {
    return Promise.resolve('even');
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('odd');
  }
})
.then(result => {
  console.log('the number is '+result);
});
```

In this case, both the branches of the condition are homogeneous, they both return a string and the result is handled in the same way.

But this not always happens, for example:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (user.type === 'admin') {
    return this.userService.getAdminTools();
  } else {
    return this.userService.getUserTools();
  }
})
.then(result => {
  // What type is the result? Maybe in this case, chaining is not the best solution! 
});
```

If you have more branches and the result is not homogeneous, maybe chaining is not the best choice. You can listen to the Promise inside another Promise, or you can just call another method which contains the async code

Answer (score 1):

Your execution flow is now separated into multiple branch which can be a wanted behavior.

When writing code, you should always think about re-usability and readability.

How an other programmer would read and understand my code easily and without getting an headache ?

The way you are putting it together is hard to follow. You should put the asynchronous action you want to perform into a separated function.

Breaking complex stuff into functions are a good practice to use in general, not only in this particular case. Try to have one function to do one thing, and have one execution flow.

```
User
 .findById(req.body.userId)
 .exec()
 .then(user => user)
 .then(user => asynchronousAddUser(user))
 .catch(err => next(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily an antipattern, but it depends a lot on why are you doing it.

There may be valid reason for breaking the chain and starting a new one, but if you find yourself doing that too often then something is wrong and probably you should rethink your flow.

I see 2 common reasons why people tend to start a new chain

1.A handler at some point during the chain makes a decision based on a condition and each branch has a totally different way of doing its work. At this point is perfectly valid to start a new chain, but I would create a new method that returns a promise. The next handler in the chain must be aware about the fact that it may receive heterogenous data

```
NewPromise()
.then( res => {
  if (someCond) {
    return OtherPromise(args)
  }
  ....
  return obj
})
.then( res => {
  //this promise must be aware that res may be heterogeneous
})
```

2.During the chain a handler receives some info that you can't easily propagate down the chain. For instance when needing 2 different piece of information that come from a DB and you need both in the end to do the work.

```
User.findById(uid1)
.then(user1 => {
  return User.finById(uid2)
})
.then(user2 => {
 // at this point user1 is not available any more
})
```

A solution for this is to have a variable outside of the chain and not start a new chain

```
var user1

User.findById(uid1)
.then(user => {
  user1 = user
  return User.finById(uid2)
})
.then(user2 => {
 // at this point user is available and has the value of user1
})
```